What is this new iOS status symbol?
I recently upgraded to iOS 18. There is a new status bar icon I do not recall:



Where the icon for location services is usually, next to the time, there is a profile of a person. It switches back a forth with the location services icon in the same place.
It is not in the iOS 18 guide to the various iOS 18 status icons.
Any idea what that means?

This is the default icon of the Work Focus, but could be any Focus with a custom icon.
Configure Focus in Settings in iOS 15 or later, and toggle on/off in Control Center.
For more information, see the iPhone User Guide:

Set up a Focus on iPhone

In the link in the question Learn the meaning of the iPhone status icons, it is at the top:

Note: If you turn on a Focus, its icon appears in the status bar.

